# how to return alternative columns on join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select, mysql-5.7

I have a table with a list of functionalities for my site. Say it has three columns:

```
id_usr - url - landing_page
1        a.php  a.html
2        b.php  b.html
3        c.php  c.html
4        d.php  d.html
```

Then I have a table where for each user i have those functionalities he can display:

```
id_usr - func
1         1
1         3
```

My query selects those functionalities that the user is allowed to see and returns their url. So with the sample data it returns

> a.php, c.php

And this is correct. The query is:

```
SELECT titolo, descr1,descr2, url, url_opz
FROM `funzioni` JOIN funz_abilitate ON funz_abilitate.id_funzione=id
WHERE funz_abilitate.id_user = $id
```

I am wondering how to improve my query to return the landing page for the functionalities that are not authorized. So the result should be:

> a.php, b.html, c.php, d.html

So for those pages that are not in range for the user, instead of url, return the value of the landing_page column.

How do I go on this with mysql 5.7?
Edited to make the columns more readible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a left join and then use a `case` expression to check if the page is allowed or not:

```sql
SELECT    f.id, CASE WHEN id_user IS NOT NULL THEN url ELSE landing_page END
FROM      funzioni f
LEFT JOIN funz_abilitate fa ON fa.id_funzione = f.id AND fa.id_user = $id
```

Comment: The query looks good, though you got the column names wrong. Actually, I think the question is confusing, in terms of column names...

Comment: @TheImpaler Yes, you are right. I changed the names to make them more readibles.

Comment: @murenik edited your post to fix an extra NULL in the select statement

Comment: @Mureinik I have added [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61755025/case-statement-options-splitted-on-two-output-columns?noredirect=1#comment109233532_61755025) because i am trying to split the case output in two columns. Is there a way to do it easily? to have url and null or null and landing on each row instead of just url or landing?