# case statement options splitted on two output columns

Tags: mysql, join, select, mysql-5.7

I have a table with a list of functionalities for my site. Say it has three columns:

```
id_usr - url - landing_page
1        a.php  a.html
2        b.php  b.html
3        c.php  c.html
4        d.php  d.html
```

Then I have a table where for each user i have those functionalities he can display:

```
id_usr - func
1         1
1         3
```

This query (from [this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61030486/how-to-return-alternative-columns-on-join/61030559?noredirect=1#comment109232983_61030559))

```
SELECT    f.id, CASE WHEN id_user IS NOT NULL THEN url ELSE landing_page END
FROM      funzioni f
LEFT JOIN funz_abilitate fa ON fa.id_funzione = f.id AND fa.id_user = $id
```

is returning what is expected but the two options from the CASE statement are returned in one single column. Is it possible to split them in two columns (first for case url and second for case landing_page)?

Expected output is something like this

```
id_usr - case url - case landing_page
    1      a.php      NULL
    2      NULL       b.html
    3      c.php      NULL
    4      d.php      NULL
```

while actually it returns:

```
id_usr - case
    1    a.php
    2    b.html
    3    c.php
    4    d.php
```

Comment: Just remove the CASE entirely and select f.id, url, landing_page

Comment: no, that woul return both values. I need to have url or landing_page not both

Comment: Then I don't think I understand the difference with what you have now. Could you give an example of the desired output?

Comment: @Aioros i edited the question to better explain

Comment: curious to understand why this question deserves a downvote. What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 2 CASE expressions:

```
SELECT    f.id, 
          CASE WHEN id_user IS NOT NULL THEN url END url,
          CASE WHEN id_user IS NULL THEN landing_page END landing_page
FROM      funzioni f
LEFT JOIN funz_abilitate fa ON fa.id_funzione = f.id AND fa.id_user = $id
```

Also you must qualify all the column names with the table's name/alias to avoid ambiguities.